# Can I sample a Vulkan SRGB image with UNORM image view?

Tags: vulkan

This is my first try for a Vulkan rendering engine and I would like insights. My image loading code currently put images in SRGB VkImage, this is of course not suitable for normal maps and other data-textures that requires a UNORM format, I would like to avoid making a separate pool for "visual" and "data" textures or in-shader color-space remapping.

So is it safe to make a "savage C casting" by using a UNORM format in my `VkImageView` on a sRGB `VkImage`? Does this cost performance ?

I target consumer desktop iGPU/dGPU as first-class plus mobile devices and I might add supports for 16bits color formats.

Comment: "*I would like to avoid making a separate pool for "visual" and "data" textures or in-shader color-space remapping*" Why would they be different "pools"? Just use appropriate image formats. What formats you use don't (usually) change what "pool" your data comes from.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I accept user-generated glTF, my images pool use file hashes as key and one might in theory reuse the same texture for sRGB and linear spaces so guessing on first use the right format is fragile.

Answer (score 0):

So I dug into Vulkan spec today and based on my interpretation the answer is: **YES**, you can do savage casting between UNORM and SRGB.

---

To cite Vulkan specification (same in 1.0.270 and 1.3.270) about *Image Views*:

> ... if image was created without the VK_IMAGE_CREATE_BLOCK_TEXEL_VIEW_COMPATIBLE_BIT flag and they are not equal **they must be compatible. Image format compatibility is defined in the Format Compatibility Classes section.** Views of compatible formats will have the same mapping between texel coordinates and memory locations irrespective of the format, with only the interpretation of the bit pattern changing.

And the *Format Compatibility Classes* section state that:

> Uncompressed color formats are compatible with each other if they occupy the same number of bits per texel block as long as neither or both are alpha formats (e.g., VK_FORMAT_A8_UNORM_KHR). Compressed color formats are compatible with each other if the only difference between them is the numeric format of the uncompressed pixels. Each depth/stencil format is only compatible with itself.

Hence any UNORM format is compatible with equivalent SRGB and vice-versa. This is also true for compressed texture and for every GPUs with SRGB support it's a mandatory "feature".

Fun-fact, according to https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/ stats as of 2023-11-14, B8G8R8A8_SRGB (99.87%) is technically "better supported" than B8G8R8A8_UNORM (99.38%) for optimally tiled sampled textures and color attachments (realistically it's safe to assume that all GPUs supports both).

Finally I fell that UNORM/SRGB performance difference is insignificant.